# Matlab: size of legend increases while saving to eps format

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, save-as

[image]I have created a matlab bar plot which I want to save in eps format. The bar plot legend is set at right corner of the figure. As I save the figure using file-> save as to eps format, the size of the legend increases and it pops out of figure. I also tried using File-> Export up and save but this also does not help. Please advise what can I do to keep the size of legend fixed while saving to eps.

An example can be seen attached.

Comment: Try Yair Altman's famous [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig)

Comment: @SardarUsama I tried it as: export_fig test2.eps. It saved a completely black image.

Comment: Do you have ghostscript installed?

Comment: @ Yes, In ubuntu I did apt-get install ghostscript and it says it is already the newest version.

Comment: @SardarUsama I changed the call to ax=gca; export_fig('test.eps','-transparent'). Now it is not black. The bar plot appears but legend size is way too small.